# Calculating Directional Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

Q) Let $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z^3+ exp(xyz)$. Find the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(1,1,1)$ in the direction to the point $(-1,2,3)$.

A) I have been given the following formula, $D_u(f(a,b,c))=u \cdot \nabla(f(a,b,c))$, where $u$ is a unit vector.

I first found $u=(-2i+j+2k)/(\sqrt((-2)^2+1^2+2^2)=(-2i+j+2k)/3$. But then I got confused when calculating $\nabla(f(a,b,c))$.

I got $\nabla(f(a,b,c))=(y^2z^3=exp(yz))i+(xz^3+exp(xz))j+(xy^2+exp(xy))$ so at the point (1,1,1) we have $\nabla(f(a,b,c))=(1+e)i+(1+e)j+(1+e)k$.

Thus giving $D_u(f(a,b,c))=(-2i+j+2k)/3\cdot(1+e)i+(1+e)j+(1+e)k=(1+e)/3$. However, I think I have calculated $\nabla(f(a,b,c))$ incorrectly as I don't know how to deal with the exponential.

Comment: Do you know what the derivative of $e^{ax}$ with respect to $x$ is? Same thing for partial derivatives.

Comment: oh so they would be of the form $yzexp(xyz)$ giving $D_u(f(a,b,c)) = (1+e,2+e,3+e) \cdot (-2,1,2)/3)= (6+5e)/3)$

Comment: You’re on the right track. I get a slightly different answer, so check your arithmetic. It looks like you might’ve made a sign error.

Comment: oops it's $(6+e)/3$